# Adding label programmatically in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having a problem adding an extra label on some of my cells in the tableview. At the moment I determine the rowheight as follows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let numberOfBusses = nearbyStops[indexPath.section].getDepartures()[indexPath.row]!.count
        if (numberOfBusses > 2) {
            return CGFloat((75/2) * numberOfBusses)
        } else {
            return 75
        }
}
```

I try to do this to add the missing label, but nothing happens:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BusDepartureTableViewCell
    let numberOfBusses = nearbyStops[indexPath.section].getDepartures()[indexPath.row]!.count
            if (numberOfBusses > 2) {
                var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
                label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
                label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                label.text = "I'am a test label"
                label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
                cell.foregroundView.addSubview(label)
            }


.........
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I've taken a picture of my current achievements and I've gotten the cell to expand, however, as you can see, there's now room for two other labels, but how do I add them?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't add a custom UIView like that in a UITableViewCell since cells are reused. Check the frame of `cell.foregroudView` and `label`

Comment: How would you do it? I'm kinda lost on how to do it different.

Comment: I'd put the view the `BusDepartureTableViewCell` (xib), and hide it if necessary.

Comment: So your would make space in the foregroundView, but just hide it and make the rows smaller when not needed? Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Cells get re"used" - that means to save memory iOS uses your UI-Elements only as an placeholder, and sets your values in

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

In that case, its much more memory efficient to create 2 (or more) different cell Layouts in Storyboard, and give every cell an different identifier.

For example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = yourPopulatingArray[indexPath.row] as Item

    var cellIdentifier = "cellLayout1"

    if item.anyPropertyToCheckforLayout {
       cellIdentifier = "cellLayout2"
    } 

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BusDepartureTableViewCell
```

Comment: Oh I see, so you would just have a couple of difference call layouts. So I would just swap cellIndentifiers in my if-statements?

Comment: Would you make it in a .xib or? I'm just used to use storyboards.

Comment: Storyboard is fine

Comment: How would you make it? Right now I have me BusDepartureTableViewCell where I want it, where would I place the other one?

Comment: You can use the same Class, just connect the labels to your Class (it doesent matter if you use an cellIdentifier where not all labels are assigned to)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121965/discussion-between-recusiwe-and-derdida).

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Whats the maximum amount of labels per cell?

Comment: You mean rows of labels? I think it is 6.

Comment: Yes. so just create 6 different Layouts containing 1 to 6 Labels and use Autolayout to define the size (constraints for each label)

Comment: How would you make the layouts? Could you provide a sample project, or it that too much to ask?

Comment: Check out this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells - just place one label under each other - and add some constraints.

Comment: Would you just make one cell? The problem is that I need to add labels, not just content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121983/discussion-between-recusiwe-and-derdida).

Comment: If I just place 6 rows of labels inside every cell as a start, I'll need to hide 4 rows when I only need 2?

Comment: No. You load the cell containing the amout of labels you need.

Comment: But how can I make more cells? I only got one prototype to set up? I might be stupid, but I can't just get it ;o)

Comment: Drag one new cell from IB into your Storyboard - just search for cell

Comment: Oh, can you have more prototype cells?

Comment: Of Course - so create as much different layouts you need

Comment: Oh, I thought you just could have one :-O So I can create all the ones I need and just give them different identifiers? I'll give it a try and get back if I get into troubles. Thanks man!